# Java class encrypt until load it to memory, can't decrpty in debug or decompile

Tags: java, class, encryption, cryptography, jvm

I have a java class file, and I don't want others to see the source code.
And the class needs to lorded to JVM by classloader in java code, like this:

```java
Class<?> classLoader = Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader");
        Method defineClass = classLoader.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass",String.class,byte[].class,int.class,int.class);
        defineClass.setAccessible(true);
        byte[] code = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64);
        Method getSystemClassLoader = classLoader.getMethod("getSystemClassLoader");
        Object objClassLoader = getSystemClassLoader.invoke(null);
        Class<?> MyClass = (Class)defineClass.invoke(objClassLoader,"MyClass", code, 0, code.length);
        MyClass.newInstance();
```

Obviously what I asked for **is not** implemented in this example, because you can see the source code buy debug or just write the `byte[] code` to a class file and decompile it.

I want to know if there is a way to achieve that the class **only decrpty in the memory**.

I tried symmetric encryption algorithm and asymmetric encryption algorithm. But both methods require writing the key for decryption in the code. So I still can’t achieve this goal.

Comment: There is a lot of pain down this road.  Any reason an obfuscator does not work for you?

Comment: I was try many obfuscator, most of them need pay, and I found a free one: proguard, but I met a problem: one class file after obfuscat it become to 3 class files.

Comment: Please read Stephen’s answer carefully.  Given your current level of experience this will not end well, and you will most likely be better of by putting restrictions in the license that must be accepted by the user to even use your software. And use an obfuscator.

Comment: Instead of `Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader")`, you can simply write `ClassLoader.class` and you can simply use `Object objClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();`, without any Reflection. Letting aside that Base64 is not an encryption at all, this still only deals with *bytecode*; you can *not* see any source code.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know if there is a way to achieve that the class only decrypt in the memory.

Sure.  There are numerous preexisting algorithms and implementations that you could use to decrypt an encrypted bytecode array in memory.

However ...

> I tried symmetric encryption algorithm and asymmetric encryption algorithm. But both methods require writing the key for decryption in the code.

... is the problem.  And it is simply not solvable.  You could try hiding the key in your code, or requesting it from a remote server.  But at some point that key needs to be available *in the clear* in JVM memory to decrypt the byte codes.

There is simply no way to solve the problem of decrypting on the user's platform without the user potentially being able to get hold of the decryption key.

And even if there was, you *still* haven't solved the problem! Because no matter what you do, the user can download the OpenJDK source code, tweak it to intercept the decrypted bytecodes *within the `defineClass` method*.  They then build the tweaked JVM, use it to run your application ... and capture your precious bytecodes.

The most practical solution is to **accept** that people will be able to get hold of the bytecodes, but make life a bit harder for them by obfuscating the bytecodes.

Or just run your application on a platform that >you< control.

---

FWIW, there is no bullet-proof way to protect binary code from reverse engineering.  If the user controls the platform and they can run your application on their platform, they can reverse engineer it ... assuming that the user has the requite skills, the tools, the time and the motivation.

Comment: There are a good news and a bad news for my situation. Good news is the user not have full contrul of the computer, actually the conputer is controled by third-part, and they is not professional. And bad news is that the computer is limited ability of access to the Internet, download key is not suitable for this situation.

Comment: You do not even need to tweak the JDK code, the out-of-the-box OpenJDK will happily pass the bytecode from `defineClass` to Agents, if the user added them to the environment.